# DB query: parameterised values or appended values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to know which one is a better approach in-terms of performance and security. I'm using MySql DB and the values are of type varchar.

Should I directly concatenate the values to form a query string and execute the query?    (or) 
Should I use parameterized queries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think security is really the only major issue here.  If you *don't* build your dynamic query using a statement, then you leave open the possibility for SQL injection, especially if some of the inputs into the query have unsterilized data coming from the outside world.  If you do use statements, then you greatly minimize the chance of this to happen.

Regarding performance, there would be some overhead in building and executing a statement, but I would wager that the penalty for using a statement over a raw string is fairly small.  The bigger issue for your performance would probably be the query itself, and how you have tuned your schema.

So, my vote is for using the statement, under the assumption that performance is a minor factor to consider here.

Answer (score 2):

You should care about data security and then performance, If you concatenate query parameters your security is risked and also this may break your query statement; this is not a better way.

So, you should parameterise your query instead of concatenation for security measure, this takes very few time to process query string.

Answer (score 1):

Using parameterized query is most recommended solution. It will prevent the threat of SQL injection as well as it provides you the flexibility of updating the query as and when required without any exposure of your query.

you can use the constant query as part of basic development but when the production code is concerned one should use parameterized query and should try to use prepared statements than normal string Statements. Using prepared Statement in Java JDBC add both performance and Security benefits.